# CFHostStartInfoResolution always fail ubunteros

Tags: iphone, ios, ip-address, lookup, cfnetwork

I have found this nice piece of code to get a hostname from a IP Address. The problem is that it always fail both on simulator and on my 3GS.

See below the code, the error is commented within:

```
+ (NSArray *)hostnamesForAddress:(NSString *)address {
    // Get the host reference for the given address.
    CFStreamError streamError;
    struct addrinfo      hints;
    struct addrinfo      *result = NULL;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family   = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (errorStatus != 0) return nil;
    CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (addressRef == nil) return nil;
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
    if (hostRef == nil) return nil;
    CFRelease(addressRef);
    BOOL isSuccess = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, &streamError);
    // always false
    if (!isSuccess){
        NSLog(@"error:%@",[self convertCFStreamErrorIntoNSError:streamError]);
        // error:Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1cd29190 {kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
        return nil;
    }

    // Get the hostnames for the host reference.
    CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
    NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
        [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
    }

    return hostnames;
}
```

Could someone say me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS lookup failure. The key part of the error message is:

```
{kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
```

From the [CFNetwork Error Codes Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html) for `kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey`:

> If an error of type `kCFHostErrorUnknown` is returned, this key returns the last error code returned by `getaddrinfo` in response to a DNS lookup. To interpret the results, look up the error code in `/usr/include/netdb.h`.

From `/usr/include/netdb.h`:

```
#define EAI_NONAME  8  /* hostname nor servname provided, or not known */
```

Try using a different DNS server.

Comment: I have forget to say that i use this code to scan my local network. I don't specially have a line to say which DNS to use. How could this be done on Iphone/simulator ?

Comment: Did u reslove the issue? @Kamax I am getting the same error

Comment: Typical consumer routers found at home doesn't come with build-in DNS server. They rely on services delivered by ISP or further, which has no knowledge about your network. First you will need to install one ([PiHole](https://pi-hole.net) for example), then assign domain names for selected local IPs, then finally your code will start to work and will receive those values.